# Error with installing scrapy : exit 1 error

Tags: python, scrapy

This is the error i get. it was working fine before, then i reinstalled python(i have added it to the system variables) and installed vscode if thats relevant.but even with windows terminal i get the same error. I did download the c++ with tools, followed the link and downloaded and installed it.

```
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\chaitali\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Chaitali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3h22t0nk\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Chaitali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3h22t0nk\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Chaitali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ttosnncb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\chaitali\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\Twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Twisted manually:
Download your version from this [Python Extension Packages website](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) and install it using (if you have Python 3.9 and `win32` platform):

```
pip3 install Twisted‑20.3.0‑cp39‑cp39‑win32.whl
```

After that you'll be able to install Scrapy using:

```
pip3 install scrapy
```

Comment: Error with Twisted: Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Try win32 version

Comment: tried something else but it worked , installed setuptools and something . but now it just shows no module named scarpy when i import it. but scrapy shell works.Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Installation Guide](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html), you should try

```
pip install Scrapy
```

It will show some warning depending on the settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).